# Ловлю ошибку 404

Tags: c#, iis

Ловлю ошибку 404 в IIS
название папки в URL дублируется
Exception 
Requested URL:/test/test/LoginPage.aspx
Если удаляю с url один test все работает

Comment: Не может ли такого быть, что оно и правда продублировано в запросе?

Comment: в самом запросе только одна папка

Answer (score -1):

Я думаю, что Ваш запрос на данный момент выглядит следующим образом:

```
"<a href="test/LoginPage.aspx"</a>";
```

Попробуйте поменять на:

```
"<a href="LoginPage.aspx"</a>";
```